# How to deploy a Sveltekit app into Back4App

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit, back4app

I would like to know how to deploy a Svelte application in Back4app.

I already have my application created in Back4app, as well as hosting enabled.

I copied one by one the files from my local path <my_app>.svelte-kit\output\server to Back4App's 'public' folder.

When clicking the deploy button, as in my 'public' svelte resources there is no index.html, Back4App recreates its default

[image]

I have also tried '***@sveltejs/adapter-node***' strategy unsuccessfully:

Deployed from my local '**build**' to the back4app remote **cloud** with **b4a deploy** command.

But the default regenerated index.html and main.js gets prevalence:

[image]